# Controller viewmodel values are received as null from my SPA FETCH POST

Tags: c#, typescript, post, asp.net-core-mvc, viewmodel

I am doing a POST back to my Asp.net Controller from my SPA. The controller has this setup:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromForm] LoginViewModel model)
    {
```

My asp.net Core API login viewmodel is:

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

My SPA is written in Typescript.

My SPA interface is:

```
interface userLogin {
  Username: string;
  Password: string;
}
```

and I declare it as such:

```
private login: userLogin,
```

and my FETCH is structured so:

```
 // Lets do a fetch!

  console.log("username, password: ", this.username, this.password);

  this.login.Username = this.username;
  this.login.Password = this.password;

  console.log("login.username, login.password", this.login);
  console.log("JSON login: ", JSON.stringify(this.login));

  const task = fetch("/api/jwt", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(this.login),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
    }
```

NOTE: When set up in POSTMAN this works.

Looking at those console logs:

```
username, password: admin password
login.ts:37 login.username, login.password {Username: "admin", Password: "password"}
login.ts:38 JSON login:  {Username: "admin", Password: "password"}
```

Here is the network tab in Chrome showing the payload:

[image]

Finally here is the controller paused at a break showing the values for the POST being null and null:

[image]

Why am I getting null on the fetch POST? What do I need to do to make my API receive the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are explicitly specifying the contentType as `application/json` and sending the json stringified version of the object. This will be send the data in the request body when the asynchronous call is made. So you need to use `FromBody` attribute so that the the framework know how to do model binding properly from the request which contains your js object/data in json format.

Change the decorator attribute from `FromForm`  to `FromBody`

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromBody] LoginViewModel model)
{
    // to do : Return something
}
```

Comment: Yes that worked thanks.  So I assume anytime I do a POST to my api my controller must have "FromBody"?